# HTML drag and drop api getdata undefined

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop

My webpage has a drag and drops function and I'm using HTML drag and drop API to do it. I try to drag and drop the SVG image in the canvas but it shows me undefined and I want the image maintain in the sidebar when I drop it in canvas.

Here is my screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1s50.png

As you can see on the screen, after I drop the image, the image is not shown on the canvas and show undefined. Is there any solution that can solve this issue?

**The code where I show the SVG**

```
<div class="container mx-0" style="width:100%; max-width: 100vw">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sidenav col-1 px-0">
                    <div class="flex-column menu" id="menu">
                        <button @click="backHome()" style="padding: 6px 19px"><i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"></i>Home</button>                           
                        <button v-for="drawer in drawers" :key="drawer.id" :class="{activeBtn:drawer.id == selected}" @click.prevent="activated(drawer.id)" >
                            <span v-html="drawer.icon"></span>{{drawer.text}}
                        </button>                          
                    </div>
                </div>

                
                <div v-if="!active" class="sub-sidenav col-3" >
                    <div class="flex-column">
                         <div class="form-group has-search">
                            <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text" placeholder="Search...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row p-3">
                            <div v-for="drawer in drawers" :key="drawer.id">
                                <div v-if="drawer.id === selected">
                                    <div class="column" v-for="item in drawer.items" :key="item.id">
                                        <div class="card" style="width: 7rem;height: 7rem">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <span class="center" v-html="item.svg" draggable="true" @dragstart="startDrag($event, item.svg)">{{item.name}}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="space col-8">
                    <div id="drop_zone" @dragover.prevent @dragleave.prevent @drop="onDrop($event)" class="workspace">{{workspace}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
export default {

    data() {
        return{
            selected: undefined,
            active: 'false',
            workspace: '',
            
            drawers: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    text: "Character",
                    icon: '<i class="fas fa-users fa-2x"></i>',
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            name: 'human1',
                            svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="43.808" height="145.733" viewBox="0 0 43.808 145.733">' +
                                ' <g id="Group_9" data-name="Group 9" transform="translate(-1183.765 -369.402)">' +
                                        '<path id="Path_84" data-name="Path 84" d="M568.051,437.983a3.832,3.832,0,0,0,2.548-2.014,3.887,3.887,0,0,0,.1-3.263l14.106-32.131-8.069-2.049-11.328,32.228a3.892,3.892,0,0,0-1.865,4.8,3.841,3.841,0,0,0,4.5,2.432Z" transform="translate(626.349 12.29)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_85" data-name="Path 85" d="M596.337,403.246l-7.848-3.7a1.737,1.737,0,0,1-.7-2.522l4.77-7.262a4.748,4.748,0,0,1,6.342-2.3,4.821,4.821,0,0,1,2.277,6.394l-2.466,8.318a1.725,1.725,0,0,1-.942,1.083A1.7,1.7,0,0,1,596.337,403.246Z" transform="translate(610.773 19.676)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_86" data-name="Path 86" d="M335.588,436.026h-4.367l-2.077-16.982h6.445Z" transform="translate(875.771 74.841)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_87" data-name="Path 87" d="M601.913,678.834h-14.08v-.18a5.5,5.5,0,0,1,5.481-5.525h8.6Z" transform="translate(610.56 -163.699)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_88" data-name="Path 88" d="M376.588,436.026h-4.367l-2.077-16.982h6.445Z" transform="translate(849.374 74.841)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_89" data-name="Path 89" d="M642.913,678.834h-14.08v-.18a5.5,5.5,0,0,1,5.48-5.525h8.6Z" transform="translate(584.164 -163.699)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_90" data-name="Path 90" d="M616.008,525.689q-.059,0-.119,0l-5.022-.375a1.617,1.617,0,0,1-1.448-1.268L600.7,475.788a.534.534,0,0,0-1.055.157l3.1,47.544a1.624,1.624,0,0,1-.421,1.224,1.6,1.6,0,0,1-1.177.519H597.32a1.6,1.6,0,0,1-1.493-1.027c-9.617-25.391-6.134-75.143-6.107-75.643l.356-.359h0l19.155,3.335.041.04c6.545,4.847,9.377,61.606,8.336,72.4a1.943,1.943,0,0,1-.474,1.245,1.6,1.6,0,0,1-1.126.465Z" transform="translate(609.755 -19.546)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<ellipse id="Ellipse_17" data-name="Ellipse 17" cx="8.748" cy="8.82" rx="8.748" ry="8.82" transform="translate(1192.936 381.911)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_91" data-name="Path 91" d="M609.9,406.117a1.321,1.321,0,0,1-.265-.027l-22.468-2.907a1.889,1.889,0,0,1-1.335-2.014l2.15-11.968c-2.85-3.591-.157-12.866,1.584-15.21l-.673-1.837a2.3,2.3,0,0,1-.03-1.483,1.817,1.817,0,0,1,.846-1.074l9.118-4.884a1.509,1.509,0,0,1,2.115.987l1.788,4.879-.027.014c4.282,2.314,8.075,4.6,5.226,16.813l3.572,16.863a2.1,2.1,0,0,1-.594,1.418A1.445,1.445,0,0,1,609.9,406.117Z" transform="translate(611.851 34.067)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_92" data-name="Path 92" d="M553.047,416.918a3.759,3.759,0,0,1,.4.441l17.622-1.228,1.89-3.884,6.187,2.11-2.684,7.2a2.849,2.849,0,0,1-2.883,1.854l-20.039-1.532a3.723,3.723,0,0,1-4,1.438,3.78,3.78,0,0,1-.693-7.017,3.715,3.715,0,0,1,4.207.613Z" transform="translate(637 3.497)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_93" data-name="Path 93" d="M613.881,399.861a1.626,1.626,0,0,1,.052-1.345l3.634-7.236a4.444,4.444,0,0,1,5.621-2.857,4.5,4.5,0,0,1,2.834,5.667l-1.4,8.014a1.616,1.616,0,0,1-.758,1.108,1.591,1.591,0,0,1-1.327.145l-7.681-2.578a1.606,1.606,0,0,1-.976-.918Z" transform="translate(593.868 18.911)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                        '<ellipse id="Ellipse_18" data-name="Ellipse 18" cx="7.124" cy="7.182" rx="7.124" ry="7.182" transform="translate(1199.474 369.402)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_94" data-name="Path 94" d="M567.6,323.04a3.7,3.7,0,0,1-2.062-.174A2.47,2.47,0,0,1,564.312,321c-1.327-8.891,6.172-8.16,7.059-8.545a9.724,9.724,0,0,0,1.568-1.154,7.283,7.283,0,0,1,4.1-.909,11.724,11.724,0,0,1,4.979.614,7.481,7.481,0,0,1,3.309,3.075,15.6,15.6,0,0,1,1.641,4.285,10.778,10.778,0,0,1,.279,5.253,6.455,6.455,0,0,1-5.848,4.725,4.873,4.873,0,0,0-2.544-5.324,7.3,7.3,0,0,0-4.85-.582,21.183,21.183,0,0,1-3.217.4C569.724,322.886,568.451,322.949,567.6,323.04Z" transform="translate(625.804 68.782)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '</g>' +
                                '</svg>'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            name: 'human2',
                            svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60.573" height="139.408" viewBox="0 0 60.573 139.408">' +
                                '<g id="Group_10" data-name="Group 10" transform="translate(-364.839 -95.836)">' +
                                    '<path id="Path_101" data-name="Path 101" d="M406.917,367.962a3.321,3.321,0,0,0-2.721,1.012,3.674,3.674,0,0,0-1.007,2.835l-11.1,5.118,5.294,3.581,9.727-5.409a3.618,3.618,0,0,0-.2-7.137Z" transform="translate(15.37 -246.348)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<ellipse id="Ellipse_26" data-name="Ellipse 26" cx="8.334" cy="8.733" rx="8.334" ry="8.733" transform="translate(369.187 97.763)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_102" data-name="Path 102" d="M110.666,433.556h4.16l1.979-16.814h-6.14Z" transform="translate(281.939 -202.537)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_103" data-name="Path 103" d="M345.178,671.685h8.193a5.35,5.35,0,0,1,5.221,5.471v.178H345.178Z" transform="translate(46.365 -442.089)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_104" data-name="Path 104" d="M59.666,433.556h4.16L65.8,416.742h-6.14Z" transform="translate(315.633 -202.537)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_105" data-name="Path 105" d="M294.178,671.685h8.193a5.35,5.35,0,0,1,5.221,5.471v.178H294.178Z" transform="translate(80.06 -442.089)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_106" data-name="Path 106" d="M293.522,546.53a1.634,1.634,0,0,1-.517-1.195l-.2-63.006,21.724-.877.16-.006,3.573,37.793.448,24.076a1.572,1.572,0,0,1-1.348,1.62l-5.273.65a1.479,1.479,0,0,1-1.171-.373,1.629,1.629,0,0,1-.533-1.154l-.939-25.578-4.558-15.924a.5.5,0,0,0-.558-.3.526.526,0,0,0-.411.5l-1.774,41.872a1.569,1.569,0,0,1-1.338,1.506l-6.089.785a1.477,1.477,0,0,1-1.2-.388Z" transform="translate(80.965 -319.492)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_107" data-name="Path 107" d="M277.416,405.1l-6.436-27.389c-2.005-8.534,2.576-17.127,10.212-19.155a12.475,12.475,0,0,1,10.556,1.972,15.823,15.823,0,0,1,6.338,10.948l4.2,32.424a1.653,1.653,0,0,1-.35,1.252,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-1.123.563l-21.879.6h-.04A1.552,1.552,0,0,1,277.416,405.1Z" transform="translate(95.698 -240.023)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_108" data-name="Path 108" d="M332.544,384.227l-16.317-8.305a5.871,5.871,0,0,1-.151-10.254,5.272,5.272,0,0,1,5.732.413l13.2,9.88,14.252-5.947a1.473,1.473,0,0,1,1.673.386l1.922,2.126a1.648,1.648,0,0,1,.408,1.285,1.612,1.612,0,0,1-.679,1.153l-12.759,8.772a7.134,7.134,0,0,1-7.283.491Z" transform="translate(67.532 -244.457)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_109" data-name="Path 109" d="M281.411,314.339a4.21,4.21,0,0,1-1.9-.411c-.266-.122-.542-.223-.807-.346-2.343-1.083-3.886-4.067-3.941-7.071a11.032,11.032,0,0,1,3.176-7.84,11.188,11.188,0,0,1,6.936-3.136c2.7-.246,5.735.573,7.242,3.26a3.269,3.269,0,0,1,.444,2.447,1.622,1.622,0,0,1-.369.678c-.673.716-1.344.178-2.03.13-.943-.065-1.79.848-2.095,1.918a6.866,6.866,0,0,0,.075,3.339l0,.02a1.9,1.9,0,0,1-.29,1.484,1.731,1.731,0,0,1-1.258.747,7.768,7.768,0,0,1-2.5,0,1.372,1.372,0,0,0-1.864.451,2.8,2.8,0,0,0-.236.814c-.332,1.812-.256,1.7-.588,3.516Z" transform="translate(92.887 -199.658)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_110" data-name="Path 110" d="M275.343,498.593a3.712,3.712,0,0,0,.582-2.963,3.55,3.55,0,0,0-1.794-2.37l1.563-12.6-5.663,2.894-.616,11.521a3.68,3.68,0,0,0,1.473,4.518,3.332,3.332,0,0,0,4.456-1Z" transform="translate(96.598 -318.986)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_111" data-name="Path 111" d="M274.229,423.209a1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.318.078l-5.716.757a1.481,1.481,0,0,1-1.2-.388,1.634,1.634,0,0,1-.517-1.2l.045-41.822a5,5,0,0,1,4.126-4.987h0a4.675,4.675,0,0,1,4.011,1.343,5.182,5.182,0,0,1,1.469,4.135l-1.661,18.023.778,22.5a1.591,1.591,0,0,1-1.016,1.567Z" transform="translate(98.362 -251.277)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                '</g>' +
                                '</svg>'
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    text: "Element",
                    icon: '<i class="fas fa-vector-square fa-2x"></i>',
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="910.908" height="529.584" viewBox="0 0 910.908 529.584">' +
                                '<g id="Group_58" data-name="Group 58" transform="translate(0 -175.412)">' +
                                    '<ellipse id="Ellipse_436" data-name="Ellipse 436" cx="48.503" cy="98.965" rx="48.503" ry="98.965" transform="translate(648.814 443.805)" fill="#3f3d56"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_298" data-name="Path 298" d="M837.384,802.263c19.426-116.551.2-232.682,0-233.84l-3.779.64c.2,1.153,19.315,116.673,0,232.571Z" transform="translate(-144.546 -97.502)" fill="#cacaca"/>' +
                                    '<rect id="Rectangle_50" data-name="Rectangle 50" width="3.833" height="49.74" transform="translate(652.802 524.872) rotate(-61.858)" fill="#cacaca"/>' +
                                    '<rect id="Rectangle_51" data-name="Rectangle 51" width="49.741" height="3.833" transform="translate(699.099 556.718) rotate(-28.158)" fill="#cacaca"/>' +
                                    '<ellipse id="Ellipse_437" data-name="Ellipse 437" cx="94.866" cy="193.564" rx="94.866" ry="193.564" transform="translate(718.989 192.58)" fill="#e6e6e6"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_299" data-name="Path 299" d="M947.834,800.179c37.944-227.66.383-454.492,0-456.756l-3.779.64c.383,2.259,37.834,228.48,0,455.487Z" transform="translate(-144.546 -97.502)" fill="#cacaca"/>' +
                                    '<rect id="Rectangle_52" data-name="Rectangle 52" width="3.833" height="97.287" transform="translate(727.657 349.519) rotate(-61.858)" fill="#cacaca"/>' +
                                    '<rect id="Rectangle_53" data-name="Rectangle 53" width="97.287" height="3.833" transform="translate(818.207 415.025) rotate(-28.158)" fill="#cacaca"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_300" data-name="Path 300" d="M738.076,800.787h-504.6a7.008,7.008,0,0,1-7-7V474.942a7.008,7.008,0,0,1,7-7h504.6a7.008,7.008,0,0,1,7,7V793.788a7.008,7.008,0,0,1-7,7Z" transform="translate(-144.546 -97.502)" fill="#e4e4e4"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_301" data-name="Path 301" d="M279.884,506.579a3,3,0,0,0-3,3V759.151a3,3,0,0,0,3,3H691.671a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V509.579a3,3,0,0,0-3-3Z" transform="translate(-144.546 -97.502)" fill="#fff"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_302" data-name="Path 302" d="M695.671,570.859V555.044H637.437V505.579H621.622v49.465H517.947V505.579H502.133v49.465H342.227V505.579H326.412v49.465H271.117v15.815h55.294v61.5H271.117v15.815h55.294v65.9H271.117v15.815H411.636V763.15h15.815V729.886h74.681V763.15h15.815V729.886H695.671V714.071H517.947V648.176H695.671V632.361H637.437v-61.5Zm-193.538,0v19.329H342.227V570.859ZM342.227,606H502.133v26.358H342.227Zm0,108.068v-65.9h69.41v65.9Zm159.906,0H427.451v-65.9h74.681Zm119.49-81.71H517.947v-61.5H621.622Z" transform="translate(-144.546 -97.502)" fill="#e6e6e6"/>' +
                                    '<circle id="Ellipse_438" data-name="Ellipse 438" cx="20.208" cy="20.208" r="20.208" transform="translate(345.286 524.559)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_303" data-name="Path 303" d="M910.513,705H0v-2.182H910.908Z" fill="#cacaca"/>' +
                                    '<circle id="Ellipse_439" data-name="Ellipse 439" cx="124.655" cy="124.655" r="124.655" transform="translate(243.261 175.412)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_304" data-name="Path 304" d="M369.135,502.707l-39.382-67.274-39.382-67.274,77.952-.469,77.952-.469L407.7,434.964Z" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<circle id="Ellipse_440" data-name="Ellipse 440" cx="44.724" cy="44.724" r="44.724" transform="translate(324.193 254.559)" fill="#fff"/>' +
                                '</g>' +
                                '</svg>'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="508.729" height="530.623" viewBox="0 0 508.729 530.623">' +
                                '<g id="Group_59" data-name="Group 59" transform="translate(0)">' +
                                    '<path id="Path_336" data-name="Path 336" d="M307.688,809.444c-4.337,1.229-8.874-.206-13.341-.267s-9.679,2.092-10.774,7.06c-1.471,6.672,5.33,11.7,11.153,13.364,22.6,6.451,46.523-1.922,69.621,1.493,9.734,1.439,19.2,4.96,28.986,5.8,22.4,1.922,44.288-10.3,66.719-8.918,11.238.69,22.161,4.783,33.4,5.44,26.891,1.571,53.422-16.534,79.747-10.047,7.434,1.832,14.413,5.567,21.778,7.729,18.621,5.468,38.225.594,56.971-4.282,3.722-.968,8.21-2.853,8.668-7.2.506-4.8-4.295-7.8-8.289-9.334-43.677-16.752-90.44-25.627-136-17.884-10.367,1.762-20.705,4.38-31.185,4.207-23.195-.383-44.509-14.259-67.28-19.335-43.147-9.618-86.288,12.82-125.9,34.673" transform="translate(-218.84 -306.476)" fill="#fbad6b" opacity="0.1"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_337" data-name="Path 337" d="M429.615,602.735H413.438V730.808s104.412,31.674,205.884,0V602.735Z" transform="translate(-262.064 -241.926)" fill="#3f3d56"/>' +
                                    '<ellipse id="Ellipse_445" data-name="Ellipse 445" cx="101.471" cy="14.46" rx="101.471" ry="14.46" transform="translate(151.375 347.037)" fill="#3f3d56"/>' +
                                    '<ellipse id="Ellipse_446" data-name="Ellipse 446" cx="101.471" cy="14.46" rx="101.471" ry="14.46" transform="translate(151.375 347.037)" opacity="0.1"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_338" data-name="Path 338" d="M671.606,251.675c-25.6,88.611-113.276,143.49-113.276,143.49s-46.176-88.788-20.578-177.4S651.027,74.276,651.027,74.276,697.2,163.064,671.606,251.675Z" transform="translate(-300.806 -43.885)" fill="#3f3d56"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_339" data-name="Path 339" d="M389.455,251.675c25.6,88.611,113.276,143.49,113.276,143.49s46.176-88.788,20.578-177.4S410.033,74.276,410.033,74.276,363.857,163.064,389.455,251.675Z" transform="translate(-251.525 -43.885)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_340" data-name="Path 340" d="M362.266,285.94c70.241,64.031,78.82,162.461,78.82,162.461s-105.3-5.384-175.544-69.415-78.821-162.462-78.821-162.462S292.025,221.909,362.266,285.94Z" transform="translate(-186.721 -97.193)" fill="#3f3d56"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_341" data-name="Path 341" d="M646.509,285.94C576.268,349.971,567.688,448.4,567.688,448.4s105.3-5.384,175.545-69.415,78.82-162.462,78.82-162.462S716.749,221.909,646.509,285.94Z" transform="translate(-313.324 -97.193)" fill="#3f3d56"/>' +
                                    '<ellipse id="Ellipse_447" data-name="Ellipse 447" cx="32.353" cy="30.297" rx="32.353" ry="30.297" transform="translate(221.963 0)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_342" data-name="Path 342" d="M277.111,407.875c2.294,7.8,10.264,12.537,10.264,12.537s4.251-7.9,1.957-15.691-10.264-12.537-10.264-12.537S274.817,400.08,277.111,407.875Z" transform="translate(-216.534 -163.022)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_343" data-name="Path 343" d="M341.362,479.322c-2.469,7.748,1.6,15.726,1.6,15.726s8.075-4.584,10.544-12.332-1.6-15.726-1.6-15.726S343.832,471.574,341.362,479.322Z" transform="translate(-237.847 -191.056)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_344" data-name="Path 344" d="M802.4,562.676c-6.061,5.759-6.459,14.594-6.459,14.594s9.427-.5,15.488-6.262,6.459-14.594,6.459-14.594S808.464,556.916,802.4,562.676Z" transform="translate(-389.178 -224.567)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_363" data-name="Path 363" d="M227.111,527.876c2.294,7.8,10.264,12.537,10.264,12.537s4.251-7.9,1.957-15.691-10.264-12.537-10.264-12.537S224.817,520.081,227.111,527.876Z" transform="translate(-199.918 -207.992)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                '</g>' +
                                '</svg>'                             
                        }
                        
                    ]
                    
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    text: "Background",
                    icon: '<i class="far fa-file-image fa-2x"></i>',
                }
            ],
          
        }
    },

    computed: {

    },

    methods: {
        backHome() {
             this.$router.push('/'); 
        },

        activated(id) {
            this.drawers.find(drawer => drawer.id === id)
            this.selected = id;
            this.active = !this.active;
        },

        startDrag (evt, item) {
            evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'
            evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy'
            evt.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', item.svg)
            console.log(item)
        },

        onDrop (evt) {
            var data = evt.dataTransfer.getData('text/html')
            evt.target.textContent = data;
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log(data)
            // const itemID = evt.dataTransfer.getData('itemID')
            // const drawer = this.drawers.find(drawer => drawer.id)
            // const item = drawer.items.find(item => item.id == itemID)
            // var data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("itemID");
            // evt.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    },   

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with you problem. The 1st thing should be thinking to use Vue way to archive your goal.

In the beginning, when dragging starts, we can capture the `item id` instead of copying the whole svg to the dom event.

```js
<span
    class="center"
    v-html="item.svg"
    draggable="true"
    @dragstart="startDrag(item.id)" // passing item id instead of whole svg
    >{{ item.name }}</span
>

data() {
  ...
  selectedItemId: -1, // state for storing selected item id
  ... 
}

methods: {
  ...
  startDrag(itemId) {
    this.selectedItemId = itemId; // set state to be the selected item id
  },
  ...
}
```

On drop, we can use the `item id` to find the svg inside the `drawers -> items`

```js
onDrop() {
   // find the SVG in drawers -> items
   const selectedItem = this.drawers[0].items.find(
      (item) => item.id === this.selectedItemId
   ); 
   // append the svg to workspace if item is found
   if (selectedItem) {
      this.workspace += selectedItem.svg;
   }
}
```

To display the svg, it is a bit tricky because I don't know about how you want to manipulate the canvas area.
e.g.

- only show 1 SVG or
- show lots of SVG or
- the SVGs can move around the canvas etc.

To display it for demo, I used `v-html` tag which **IS NOT SAFE** and sanitized

```html
<div class="space col-8">
    <div
        id="drop_zone"
        @dragover.prevent
        @dragleave.prevent
        @drop="onDrop"
        class="workspace"
    >
        <span v-html="workspace"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is the codesandbox for demonstration, the style is way off as I do not have your CSS, still it is workable:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-sea-gh42u?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

---

Resize and move around example by using `vue-movable`

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lamport-p57yg?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Finished Look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6kgS.png

```js
<div
    id="drop_zone"
    @dragover.prevent
    @dragleave.prevent
    @drop="onDrop"
    ref="dropZone"
>
    <Moveable
    class="moveable"
    @drag="handleDrag"
    @scale="handleScale"
    @rotate="handleRotate"
    @warp="handleWarp"
    v-bind="moveable"
    v-for="(wp, index) of workspace"
    :key="index"
    >
    <img :src="wp.svg" />
    </Moveable>
</div>

data: {
  ...
  workspace: [],
  ...
}

onDrop() {
    const selectedItem = this.drawers[0].items.find(
        (item) => item.id === this.selectedItemId
    );
    if (selectedItem) {
        this.workspace.push(selectedItem);
    }
},
handleDrag({ target, transform }) {
    console.log("onDrag", transform);
    target.style.transform = transform;
},
handleScale({ target, transform }) {
    console.log("onScale", transform);
    target.style.transform = transform;
},

handleRotate({ target, transform }) {
    console.log("onRotate", transform);
    target.style.transform = transform;
},
handleWarp({ target, transform }) {
    console.log("onWarp", transform);
    target.style.transform = transform;
},
```

Comment: It is working! As you say, I actually want to do something like Canva.com but is mainly for people to make an illustration based on their needs. I want it able to combine a lot of SVG together such as the background, character and also element to form an illustration while the SVG also can move around in the Canva and resize too. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Updated the answer. it is quite a large topic to do what you want to do so I just make a sample for you to have a glimpse of it. You need to read the vue-movable library https://github.com/probil/vue-moveable to control the element in details. You may need to twist your architecture as well to support different kinds of elements. Not a one day or one answer job.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will try it out. And may I know how to set for all drawer since this one this. drawers[0].items.find() is only for one drawer and I tried to drag for other items in other drawers too. I tried to figure it out to use switch case but seem doesn't work.

Comment: updated second codesandbox, you just need to make use of your `this.selected` to find out which drawer is selected and apply it `drawers[this.selected].items.find()`. But the architecture should need to change to support dynamic element. using `v-html` is not recommended

Comment: Oh, I see,  I have tried a lot of methods to get the SVG code but so far v-html is work for me hahaha so I keep using it until now.

Comment: Another thing is, I will add a function to change the colour of the SVG after this, and I using vue-swatches to manage the colour and used for other pages also, I bind the class in SVG fill for changing the colour. So I use v-html.

Comment: you can see the 2nd codesandbox, the svg is loaded in image src. I think it is more appropriate and i see canvas.com do the same as well.

Comment: Before that, I used img src to load the SVG, but I have no idea how to change the colour in the SVG code, do you if I bind SVG fill with the class and load it in img src, is this workable?

Comment: you can read this .https://stackoverflow.com/a/58218256/15569492 if you really need v-html, you need to sanitise it. Otherwise, your app may have security risk.

Comment: if you need to modify the properties of svg, image will not suitable to you. the svg will need to be a component and generate the component dynamically https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remind and concerned^^. Since this is my uni final year project so this web application won't be launched globally and uni will own it after this but I will take note of this important tip for future reference. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, Mic Fung, I have another question regarding save all the SVG in the workspace into the database, could you please have a look if you are free.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/67747680/10742443

Comment: Okay. will take a look. focus on react section recently and didn't notice the questions on vue. lol